# HTML <button> placed inside of a html table, tagged with id , not responding to jquery

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, asp.net

I have a problem. I am currently developing an simple CRUD single page app, because i am learning ways of jquery. So what i wanted to do is to use buttons inside of a table to link people to the profile of the user in the table. Here is the code. that i have.

HTML Document:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>

    <script src="Scripts/jquery-3.3.1.min.js"></script>
    <script src="Script.js"></script>
    <script src="Scripts/jquery-3.3.1.js"></script>
    <style>
        table {
            font-family: arial, sans-serif;
            border-collapse: collapse;
            width: 100%;
        }

        td, th {
            border: 1px solid #dddddd;
            text-align: left;
            padding: 8px;
        }

        tr:nth-child(even) {
            background-color: #dddddd;
        }
    </style>
</head>
<body>
    <div id="showpage">
        <h2>Users list</h2>



        <input id="search" style="float:right" type="text" placeholder="search...." />
        <table id="table">
            <tr>
                <th>Name</th>
                <th>Age</th>
                <th>Email</th>
                <th>Blogs</th>
                <th>View Profile</th>
            </tr>
            <tr>
                <td id="criteria">John Smith</td>
                <td>20</td>
                <td id="criteria">john@mail.com</td>
                <td>10</td>
                <td><button id="profilebutton">View</button></td>
            </tr>
            <tr>
                <td id="criteria">Adam Smith</td>
                <td>25</td>
                <td id="criteria">adam@mail.com</td>
                <td>2</td>
                <td><button id="profilebutton">View</button></td>
            </tr>
            <tr>
                <td id="criteria">Lily Smith</td>
                <td>18</td>
                <td id="criteria">jlily@mail.com</td>
                <td>1</td>
                <td><button id="profilebutton">View</button></td>
            </tr>
            <tr>
                <td id="criteria">Trevor Philips</td>
                <td>45</td>
                <td id="criteria">trevrn@mail.com</td>
                <td>3</td>
                <td><button  id="profilebutton">View</button></td>
            </tr>
            <tr>
                <td id="criteria">Michael DiSanta</td>
                <td>44</td>
                <td id="criteria">mike@mail.com</td>
                <td>1</td>
                <td><button id="profilebutton">View</button></td>
            </tr>
            <tr>
                <td id="criteria">Andrea Pirlo</td>
                <td>47</td>
                <td id="criteria">pirlo@mail.com</td>
                <td>4</td>
                <td><button id="profilebutton">View</button></td>
            </tr>
        </table>
    </div>


    <div id="profilepage">

<h2>ProfileName</h2>
        <table>
            <tr>
                <td>Blog</td>
                <td>Description</td>
                <td>Date</td>
            </tr>
        </table>
    </div>
</body>
</html>
```

Script.js :

```
    $(document).ready(function () {
        $('#profilepage').hide();
        $(document).on('click', 'profilebutton', function () {

            $('#showpage').hide();
            $('#profilepage').show();
        });



        $('#search').keyup(function () {

            search_table($(this).val());

        });

        function search_table(value) {

            $('table tr').each(function () {

                var found = 'false';
                $(this).each(function () {
                    if ($(this).text().toLowerCase().indexOf(value.toLowerCase()) >= 0) {

                        found = 'true';
                    }

                });
                if (found == 'true') {
                    $(this).show();

                }
                else {
                    $(this).hide();
                }
            });
        }




});
```

As you can see i tried everything, from directly pointing to the button ( $('#profilebutton') ) to this , but nothing seems to work, i run the app (i am developing in asp.net platform), search code works just fine, but buttons in the table are unresponsive. Can someone please point out what am i doing wrong? I would be very grateful.

Comment: `id`s are meant to be unique. When you use an `id` selector (`#id`) you are grabbing only one element. Use classes instead.

Comment: Your selector is also incorrect.  This selector: `'profilebutton'` is looking for this element: `<profilebutton />` which of course doesn't exist.  Follow the above advice to use classes instead of ids for non-unique values, and also correct your selector select based on that criteria.  (Note that you have other id-based selectors which are correct.  So it seems like this is more of a typo than a misunderstanding of how it works.)

Comment: It looks like you're including both "jquery-3.3.1.min.js" and "jquery-3.3.1.js". Because you import the second copy after your script has run, the jQuery environment will lose track of anything your own script does.

Comment: Can you update your example code to what you have now? Also, I admit, the `$(document).on("click", selector, callback);` call you have there is the first time I see someone doing  it like this in jQuery. What I would do, if I were you, is `$(".profilebutton").on("click", function() { /* do stuff */ });`

Comment: Thank you Kamil and other guys, you helped me so much, i love you :)

Answer (score 0):

Try

```
$('#profilebutton').each(function(){ $(this).click(); })
```

instead of

```
$(document).on('click', 'profilebutton'...
```

As profilebutton represents an array/collection of buttons..